# Question about max flow: If all edges have capacity in integers, does a max flow exist where the flow in every edge is in integers?

Tags: algorithms, network-flow

Let's assume that for every $e\in E$ it holds that $c(e)$ is an integer. Does it mean that there exists a max flow $f$ that for every $e\in E$ it holds that $f(e)$ is an integer? It sounds obvious but I can't exactly say why it is true.

Comment: Have you ever heard of [the max-flow min-cut theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem), the most famous and the most basic theorem in the theory of flow network? Have you ever heard of any algorithm that computes the maximum flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [integral flow theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem#Integral_flow_theorem) says "yes".